# How to redirect syslog entries from a program, that's called by a bash script?

Tags: bash, debian, syslog, rsyslog

I have an application, where the main program is run as a daemon, so it uses a service file. However, the initialization process is quite long, that's why I have a starter bash script (that handles interfaces, inputs...etc and then calls the program).

Here's how the program is actually called:
Systemctl daemon -> service file start script with bash -> starter script -> app

Service file entry:

```
[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to/start/script.sh
```

Start script entry for the app:

```
./app -a an_input -b another_input
```

The app is sending logs via syslog, however since it's called from inside of a bash script, in /var/log/syslog all app entries have a syslogtag like "bash[PID]" format, and therefore I cannot sort by that. I also log from the start script with logger, that's working fine.

Is there a way I can somehow make sure that the app uses the desired tag, with some syslog magic? Or is there any way to strictly use a given tag when syslog is called inside of a program?

Comment: Try `exec ./app -a an_input -b another_input`